# How Can I Dynamically Select the Names With the Maximum Frequency in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My current project is basically importing my friend list from Facebook and then selecting the first name with the highest frequency i.e. the most common name. I've been trying to set up the subquery like this ::

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, first_name 
FROM Friends GROUP BY first_name ORDER BY count DESC;
```

and then after that I'm stumped... I've been trying to use a MAX function in the where clause but it wouldn't compile, so then i tried putting it in a subquery and I still couldn't get it to work. Do I need to use a join?

Comment: What isn't working? What output are you getting that's not correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   first_name
FROM     friends
GROUP BY first_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

or this, that could return more than one row if more than one name has the maximum number of repetitions:

```
SELECT first_name
FROM friends
GROUP BY first_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FRIENDS
                   GROUP BY first_name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
```